# Find a counter example for the claim if a finite group G acts on X, then X must be finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra

If the group action is an identity map, then G can be finite while X can be infinite?

Comment: You mean let $G$ be the trivial group and have its only element act on $X$ as the identity map? Absolutely.

Comment: The group action is not an identity map. You probably mean the constant map.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can always make every element of $G$ act as the identity.  In this way any group can act on any set.

For a non-trivial example take any finite subgroup of $\mathbb C^\ast$ (such as $\pm 1$).  This subset acts on $\mathbb C$ via multiplication.

Or let $X$ be any nonempty set that $G$ acts on (for example, $G$ itself!) and then define the action of $G$ on $\mathbb N \times X$ via $g\cdot(a, x) = (a, g\cdot x)$.  No matter what $X$ you choose $\mathbb N \times X$ is infinite.  So in fact **every** finite group acts nontrivially on some infinite set.